# How to revoke a token in Discord OAuth2.0?

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord, bearer-token

In order to use Discord's API I need a token, and to get it I open a link such as
`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_url>&response_type=token&scope=identify`

Then I set the token as `authorization` (in format `Bearer <token>`) header of requests that are issued to the Discord's API.

Let's say I want to "logout", so that a certain token can't be used anymore to do such requests. In this case I have to revoke that token, right?

So after reading Discord's documentation and making some adjustments I decided that I have to make a POST request to a URL such as 
`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token/revoke`, and `content-type` header of this request should be set to `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

When I do it I'm getting an error message from discord's server with message saying `{error: "invalid_client"}`

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in actual format of the data I was sending. I was sending JSON data because I thought that setting specific headers would automatically turn the data into the right format, but it turns out I had to use `FormData` object to create the data in the right format, and after that I also removed the lines where I'm setting the header explicitly, after these steps everything worked fine.

Comment: So can you please explain me how did you do it? I'm also working on it and can't figure it out.

Comment: @GaborSzita I don't have the code right now, but you can simply google for FormData examples. The FormData should be created with new keyword. let data = new FormData(); and so on. Then you can add your key:value pairs to it, and after that you can send it

Comment: I have tried for a while now and didnt get it working, can you post a full snippet of code that works with the current version?

Answer (score 4):

If you come by this question and are wondering what is the full API call to revoke the token, here it is:

```
POST https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token/revoke
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
data:
  client_id: <client_id>
  client_secret: <client_secret>
  token: <access_token>
```

Comment: Thanks.. I think it's working but not 110% sure. I follow this and get a 200 OK and a response object of `{}`. Does that mean it's successful? In other revocation endpoints, it gives you `{revoked: true}` so it's more explicit

Comment: To be sure, you can check if you can still use the token.